# listview item is not added on button click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have an issue with adapter adding data to listview on button click.

I have a activity called createteam that has name and email edittext and a createplayer button. On click createplayer button, the name and email should be added to list view.

I want to use an adapter for doing that(so that I can learn).

**Update: 
 Onclicking the button the the first entry gets added but when I  fill in the**
 **edittexts again, the listview does get updated. I am notifying the adapter when I update**
 **the data but only first entry gets and remains added to list view**

create_team.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/teamname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:hint="Team Name"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:textStyle="bold">

    </EditText>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/addplayer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:text="Add Player"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:textStyle="bold">

    </Button>



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_addplayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 >
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/createplayer"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:text="Create Player"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:textStyle="bold">

    </Button>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:textStyle="bold">

    </EditText>
        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@color/blue"

    android:hint="Email "
     android:textStyle="bold"

    android:gravity="center">

    </EditText>



  </LinearLayout>

      <ListView 
          android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

add_player_listview.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="2">



<TextView android:id="@+id/name" 
android:textSize="20sp" 
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:color="@color/blue"
android:textColor="#FFFF00" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/email"
android:textSize="15sp" 
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:color="@color/mustard"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

CreateTeamActivity.java

```
package com.recscores.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.recscores.android.PlayerInfo;

public class CreateTeamActivity extends ListActivity {
    Button createPlayer;
    EditText Email;
    EditText Name;
    private ArrayList<PlayerInfo> newList;
    private PlayerAddAdapter newAdpt;
    private int i = 0;
    private ListView lv;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_team);

    newList = new ArrayList<PlayerInfo>();

    // CREATE TEAM
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.app_background2);

    createPlayer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.createplayer);


    Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    newAdpt = new PlayerAddAdapter(CreateTeamActivity.this,android.R.id.list,newList);
    lv.setAdapter(newAdpt);

    createPlayer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
        //  newList = new ArrayList<PlayerInfo>();
            PlayerInfo info = new PlayerInfo();
            info.SetName(Name.getText().toString());
            info.SetEmail(Email.getText().toString());
            newList.add(info);          
            newAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //Thread.sleep(2000);

            Name.setText("");
            Email.setText("");


            }
            });


    }


}
```

PlayerAddAdapter.java

```
package com.recscores.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class PlayerAddAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlayerInfo> {
    private Activity activity;
    //private final Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<PlayerInfo> items;


    public PlayerAddAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<PlayerInfo> items){
    super(a,textViewResourceId,items);
    this.items=items;
    this.activity = a;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView name;
        public TextView email;
    }
    @Override


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 vi.inflate(R.layout.add_player_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.email = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.email);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        final PlayerInfo custom = items.get(position);
        if (custom != null) {
            **holder.name.setText(custom.GetName());
            holder.email.setText(custom.GetEmail());
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

PlayerInfo.java

```
package com.recscores.android;

public class PlayerInfo {

    private String name="";
    private String email="";

        public void SetName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        }
        public String GetName(){
        return this.name;
        }

        public void SetEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
        }
        public String GetEmail(){
        return this.email;
        }
}
```

Comment: You are not inflating `View v` variable. you need to use `v = vi.inflate(...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater vi =(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.add_player_listview, null);
```

Change your code like this. You are not setting values to v variable.

Comment: Rajesh CP, Thanks a lot for pointing out the issue. Now Null pointer access error is gone. But the code still does not do anything. Nothing happens on button click. Please help.

Comment: onClick what should happen ? It will get added to the bottom of the list check the last item

Comment: the list view remain blank...no row added

Comment: onclick createplayer button, email and name edittexts input should get added to listview, the list view remain blank...no row added....As you can see in createteamactivity.java, on click createplayer button my edit fields do get reset to blank but nothing happens to listview...it remains blank...

Comment: Rajesh: With your help I have made some progress. Now the first entry gets added to list view but nothing happens when I reenter the values 2nd time(first one remain in the listview but 2nd row does not get added)..any suggestions..please help.

Comment: Kindly update your question with current code or share the entire project some where

Comment: Actually I updated the code....I forgot  lv.setAdapter(newAdpt); in the code thats why listview was not getting popupated....I added this..now the listview gets populated with the first entry...but nothing happens after that(meaning what I fill edittext again and click button..2nd entry does not get added)

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I am still trying to resolve  this...do you have any suggestion?thanks

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` of your `button` call `list.notifyDataSetChanged()`. It will refresh your list.

Incase if doesn't work just check getCount() of your adapter what value it is returning. If it is returning `0` your list will not show any data even you call `list.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Make an `arrayList` in your `adapter` and add new items into that. and from `getCount()` return size of `arrayList`.

Comment: Ankit: Thanks for your help..I made some progress. Now the first entry gets added but when nothing happens when I try to add another another.Can you please show me how to write getCount() method? BTW I am refreshing the adapter already  newAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();                     Regards

Comment: can you post you getCount method?